# What is concentrated payload?

Tags: aircraft-performance, weight-and-balance

Reading about the Embraer c390 millennium. Two different payloads are listed. Maximum concentrated payload and distributed payload. What is the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A concentrated load is one single very heavy thing that is compact- like a big electric motor strapped down for shipment on a pallet, that takes up little floor space relative to its weight. A distributed load is spread out, like a line of suitcases stretching from the front to the back of the cargo compartment, occupying the entire floor.

Even though that huge electric motor might weigh exactly the same as that long line of suitcases, the stresses imposed by each load on the airframe will be quite different, and they will have distinctly different effects on the pitch response of the plane in flight.